# In Solr - relevancy is affected wrong by spaces

Tags: solr

I have indexed 2 user documents with a field fullName:

```
fullname=Matt Cain
fullName=Matt Harvey
```

when i search for

```
fullName:Matt Harvey
```

the term Matt Cain gets a higher score, but if i search for

```
fullName:matt OR fullName:harvey
```

then Matt Harvey comes first.

How can i correctly configure my schema.xml so that solr takes care of it correctly without breaking the query up manually?

here are some relevant parts from my current schema.xml

```
<fields>
    <!-- general -->
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
    <field name="type" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <field name="firstName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="lastName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="fullName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="email" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="workPlace" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="geoArea" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="gender" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="tags" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="birthDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="followersCount" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="featuredLevel" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <field name="fbId" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
    <field name="imageUrl" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true"/>

    <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>

</fields>
```

....

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

if there are other parts needed to answer the question i'll be happy to post them. didnt want to post the whole thing..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fullName:Matt Harvey` only searches for `fullName:Matt` according to the [Lucene Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html). To fix this you need to search for `fullName:"Matt Harvey"`